# Can inline functions be called inside a loop?

Tags: c++, function, inline

I would like to know whether an inline function can be invoked inside a loop..is using an inline function in a loop a syntax error or is it not advisable??

Comment: If it is a syntax error, the compiler will tell you. Did you ask your compiler first?

Comment: You should really just try these things

Comment: There's no difference vs. calling non-inlined functions. Why are you even asking??

Comment: You shouldn't criticise someone for asking.
There are a lot of cases when something seem to be working, but is just coincidence.
And a lot of cases where something is working on 1 compiler, but generally is syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Inline functions can be used exactly like normal functions. You can call them wherever you want, take their address, anything.

`inline` basically does two things:

1. Tell the compiler to try to avoid a function call, although the compiler will most likely make its own decision there.
2. Allow redefinition which is important for template functions and in-class defined member functions. The definition of an `inline` function needs to be present in every translation unit calling the function.

So yes, you can call `inline`-functions in loops, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Not just *allow* redefinition, but *require* it, in any translation unit in which the function is (odr-)used, before the first use.

Comment: @BoBTFish thx, edited. Btw, cppr says that the definition does not need to be present before the call, just somewhere in the translation unit.

Comment: Hmm, that does make sense. Probably I'm an idiot, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Inline functions are semantically identical to non-inline ones, with no restrictions on where you can call them.

The only difference is that they can be multiply defined, and must be defined in every translation unit that calls them. This is so that the definition is available where the function is called, allowing the compiler to inline the call if it decides that it should.

You may be under the impression that all calls to an inline function are inlined. That is not the case. The keyword might (or might not) influence the decision, but it doesn't force it, and it's not an error to call the function in ways (such as recursion) that can't be inlined.

Answer (score 1):

You should really just try it, but since I'm here, **yes you can**.
If you think about it, it's exactly the same as typing your function code inside the loop (i.e. inlining).